# scan_tools runtime error undefined symbol cblas_dtrsv ubuntu 12.04.2LTS

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have downloaded the scan_tools source code from git: it did build successfully, but at runtime I get:

"laser_scan_matcher_node: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgsl.so.0: undefined symbol: cblas_dtrsv".

When I run ldd on the laser_scan_matcher_node binary, I see that libgsl.so.0 is linked, but NOT libgslcblas.

I am on ubuntu 12.04.2LTS.

What could I do to make it work, please ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57252/scan_tools-runtime-error-undefined-symbol-cblas_dtrsv-ubuntu-12.04.2lts/) by [micmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3287/micmac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By browsing the web, I have found a way to build it on ubuntu 12.04.2.LTS.
In fact only the laser_scan_matcher triggers the symbol lookup error.

STEPS:

1. rosmake scan_tools
2. sudo apt-get remove binutils-gold (this one doesn't link libgslcblas correctly, as stated on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405601/gnu-scientific-library-cblas-symbol-lookup-error ).
3. rosmake --pre-clean laser_scan_matcher : the build will not finish correctly (problems with libboost),but next step will finish the build:
4. sudo apt-get install binutils-gold
5. rosmake laser_scan_matcher : the build finishes successfully.

This time when I run "ldd laser_scan_matcher_node" on the binary, libgslcblas is linked correcly, and the laser_scan_matcher works :)

---

Originally posted by [micmac](https://answers.ros.org/users/3287/micmac/) with karma: 141 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0